# How to move a data set from one sheet to another based on criteria using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to move data from one Table called `Raw_Data` on `sheet Raw Data` to another table called `Phone_Number` on `sheet No Quality`.

I have **16 columns** on the tables and I need to confirm if the **Raw Data table** has the words **No Quality** or **PH Phone** on the **15th column**. If it does then I want to move the data to the No Quality sheet and paste it into the table there. Once it is pasted I want to erase the data off of the Raw Data table.

I have tried a few different methods but can't seem to get them to work. Here is the first method I'm using

```
Sub Numbers()

    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet, newSheet As Worksheet
    Dim dataTable As ListObject, newTable As ListObject
    Dim dataCount As Long
    Dim checkOne As String, checkTwo As String
    Dim copyRange As Range
    
    Set dataSheet = Worksheets("Raw Data")
    Set newSheet = Worksheets("No Quality")
    Set dataTable = dataSheet.ListObjects("Raw_Data")
    Set newTable = newSheet.ListObjects("Phone_Number")
    checkOne = "PH Phone"
    checkTwo = "No Quality"
    dataCount = dataSheet.ListObjects("Raw_Data").ListRows.Count
    dataValue = dataSheet.ListObjects("Raw_Data").DataBodyRange(dataCount, "O").Value
    dataLocation = dataSheet.ListObjects("Raw_Data").DataBodyRange(dataCount, "O").row - 1

    For i = 2 To dataLocation

        valueToCheck = dataSheet.ListObjects("Raw_Data").DataBodyRange(i, "O")
        If valueToCheck = checkOne Or valueToCheck = checkTwo Then
            'Errors out on the line below
            Worksheets("Raw Data").Range(Cells(i, "A"), Cells(i, "P")).Copy

            Worksheets("No Quality").Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).row, 1).PasteSpecial
        End If

    Next i
    
End Sub
```

I can get it to partially run but it will never complete. I attempted to use the following code but I'm not sure how to change it to run in the way that I needed it.

```
Sub NoQuality()

    Dim dataTable As Range
    Dim newTable As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set dataTable = Worksheets("Raw Data").ListObjects("Raw_Data").DataBodyRange
    Set newTable = Worksheets("No Quality").ListObjects("Phone_Number").DataBodyRange
    dataTable.Copy newTable.Offset(tbl2.Rows.Count)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    tbl1.ClearContents
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[Results of New Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEPoV.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably get away with a lot less code.  Please try the following & let me know how it goes.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Numbers()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheets("Raw Data")
Set ws2 = Sheets("No Quality")

With ws1.ListObjects("Raw_Data").Range
    .AutoFilter 15, "No Quality", 2, "PH Phone"
    .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Copy ws2.Cells(2, 1)
    .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).EntireRow.Delete
    ws1.ListObjects("Raw_Data").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: So I added that code and ran it. It was able to pull the data, but it didn't paste it into the table but below it. Also it didn't delete the rows from the Raw Data table. I will add a picture of what it looks like into the original question.

Comment: Code amended, please try again.